# Charts plugin for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, charts

I would like to integrate charts in my PhoneGap project. I was looking for many different charts for web browsers:

1. chart.js
2. flot
3. chartjs devExpress
4. D3.js
5. Raphael.js
6. jqPlot

But which will be the best suit for realtime PhoneGap apps?

Comment: Other than working for realtime phonegap what features do you require? What kind of pricing is acceptable?

Comment: @Nick Wilde it is a simple demo app, so I would like to go for open source charts... just basic features like different type of charts, refresh charts without reloading the page, ease of use with phonegap... BTW any suggestions is fully acceptable

Comment: what particular chart types do you need?

Answer (score 2):

I see in your comments that you are looking for open source because this is a demo project. But have you considered a full JS Charting library? They generally have a few more options than a jquery plugin might, and can save time compared to, say, D3.

Wondering if [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com/) fits the bill for your project... It handles real time data in a few different ways and can handle larger data sets. It could work for your demo, too - free trial is unlimited and the full version (contains a watermark).

I'm with the ZingChart team so if you have any questions, feel free to reach out.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
 is my go-to JavaScript library for creating charts easily. It provides many pre-built charts like area charts, bar charts, calendar charts, pie Charts, geo charts, and more.

Google charts also comes with various customization options that help in changing the look of the graph. Charts are rendered using HTML5/SVG to provide cross-browser compatibility and cross platform portability to iPhones, iPads, and Android. It also includes VML for supporting older IE versions.

Here’s a great [list of examples](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) built using Google charts.